# mysql - why is a closing bracket considered equal to ö (o umlaut)?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I found a very strange behavior comparing characters in mysql.

The simplest function to reproduce is this:

```
set names utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
drop function if exists contains_bracket;
delimiter ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`db`@`%` FUNCTION `contains_bracket`(str varchar(255) CHARSET utf8) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
  begin
    declare i, result int;
    declare letter varchar(1);
    set result = 0;
    set i = 1;
    set str = lower(str);
    while i <= length(str) do
      set letter = substring(str, i, 1);
      if letter = ']' then
        set result = 1;
      end if;
      set i = i + 1;
    end while;
    return result;
  end;;
delimiter ;
```

The function should return 1 if the argument contains a closing bracket `]`, and 0 otherwise. Curiously in this function o umlaut `ö` is considered equal to `]`.

Test it like this :

```
select contains_bracket('[a]'), contains_bracket('abc'), contains_bracket('äöü'), contains_bracket('ö')
```

will give

```
-------------------------------
| '[a]' | 'abc' | 'äöü' | 'ö' |
-------------------------------
|  1    |  0    |  1    |  1  |
-------------------------------
```

What is going on here? Can anybody explain ? Is it a bug in mysql that `']' = 'ö'` is true when using `utf8_general_ci` or is there something that I'm missing?

**Edit:**

The connection charset and collation is very important, because stored functions and procedures keep the charset and collation that was active during their creation for their lifetime.

Keep also in mind, that in phpmyadmin the data exchange is by default in utf8. The connection collatiom does not change this. For instance, when the connection collation is latin1, and we send non ascii characters in string literals in the query, their value will be corrupted (e.g when we type `'ä'` (utf8), the server will see `_latin1'Ã¤'`)

Comment: can you add  DETERMINISTIC before the first begin and tell me if you are still receiving incorrect values?

Comment: you might have a reason but why on the earth are you looping through if you can use mysql native functions i.e instr?

Comment: @krishKM I'm looping for other reasons. This is just a function to demonstrate the phenomenon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really *does* look as a problem of mismatching character sets.

Please fix your `declare letter varchar(1);`

It should be `declare letter varchar(1) CHARSET utf8;`

**What's going on?**

In this assignment

`set letter = substring(str, i, 1);`

the `substring` result is being converted to `latin1` as `letter` is declared as `varchar(1)` with charset latin1 by default.

So in the comparison `if letter = ']'` we have `ö` in `latin1` at the left and `]` at the right.

**Why they're considered equal?**

MySQL uses a binary representation to compare strings. There is a function `WEIGHT_STRING()` in v.5.6 and above.

> This function returns the weight string for the input string. The
>   return value is a binary string that represents the comparison and
>   sorting value of the string.

Let's see the `WEIGHT_STRING(letter)`:

```
set names utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
drop function if exists contains_bracket;
delimiter ;;
CREATE FUNCTION `contains_bracket`(str varchar(255) CHARSET utf8) RETURNS varchar(255)
  begin
    declare i int;
    declare result varchar(255);
    declare letter varchar(1);
    set result = '';
    set i = 1;
    set str = lower(str);
    while i <= length(str) do
      set letter = substring(str, i, 1);
      if letter = ']' then
        set result = concat(weight_string(letter), ' = ', letter);
        set i = length(str); -- exit the loop 
      end if;
      set i = i + 1;
    end while;
    return result;
  end;;
delimiter ;
```

The test:

```
select contains_bracket('[a]'), contains_bracket('abc'), contains_bracket('äöü'), contains_bracket('ö');
```

will give

```
---------------------------------
| '[a]' | 'abc' | 'äöü' |  'ö'  |
---------------------------------
| ] = ] |       | ] = ö | ] = ö |
---------------------------------
```

Using the correct charset in `letter` declaration fixes this issue.

And more simple way to determine if a string contains another string:

```
select if(locate(']', '[a]'), 1, 0); -- returns 1
select if(locate(']', 'äöü'), 1, 0); -- returns 0
```

Comment: I agree, it *does* look as a problem of mismatching character sets, but it *does not* seem to be related to conversion between latin1 and utf8.

Comment: Thank you, I've extended my answer.

Comment: I don't get those results; what do you have for `show variables like '%col%';`?

Comment: I used mysql 5.7.18 with default settings.

Comment: Utf8 uses up to 3 bytes to represent a character in mysql.

Comment: Basic Latin letters, digits, and punctuation signs use one byte.

    Most European and Middle East script letters fit into a 2-byte sequence: extended Latin letters (with tilde, macron, acute, grave and other accents), Cyrillic, Greek, Armenian, Hebrew, Arabic, Syriac, and others.

    Korean, Chinese, and Japanese ideographs use 3-byte or 4-byte sequences.

Comment: This was very helpful, since you reproduced the behavior. Thank you also for the insight of what happens behind the scenes (especially `weight_string`), though some details are not accurate: *So in the comparison if letter = ']' we have the 1st byte of ö at the left and ] at the right.* In fact, we do not have the 1st byte of `_utf8'ö'`, but we have the byte representing `_latin1'ö'`.

Comment: @Lorenz, thank you again, I've checked and corrected my answer. You're right it was `_latin1'ö'`. Also thanks for the interesting question!

Answer (score 1):

This would be a lot shorter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `contains_bracket`(str varchar(255) CHARSET utf8)
       RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
  RETURN str LIKE '%]%';
  end;;
```

Why not use that?

OK, assuming the real task does not allow for using `LIKE`...

There is a bug:  Use `CHAR_LENGTH()`, not `LENGTH()`.

OK, that does not change the results that I get.  But I get

```
mysql> select contains_bracket('[a]'), contains_bracket('abc'), contains_bracket('äöü'), contains_bracket('ö')\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
   contains_bracket('[a]'): 1
   contains_bracket('abc'): 0
   contains_bracket('äöü'): 0
     contains_bracket('ö'): 0
```

So, I have to say "works for me".

Perhaps there is some other setting in my.cnf that is amiss?  What version of MySQL are you using?

Well, I think the following is the real answer, since I have seen it on German keyboards.  The keyboard shows `ö`, but the code transmitted was `]`.  (Seems like I was on assignment in Stuttgart in the '80s and had to use a German terminal to code C.)

Suggest you do the following -- pepper the stored proc with `SELECT HEX(...)` to see you are actually searching for `]`.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I think they are pointing to the right direction. You said *works for me*. I must admit that after deleting and recreating the function à couple of times I'm no longer able to reproduce, but I'm  not able to correct the problem in the production database with the original function neither. I'm really confused.

Comment: As I state above, the function created with the same statement not always behaved the same, depending on some settings. If possible I'll add these details to make the problem repeatable for everyone. I think I need to elude the mystery stated in order to be able to give all the details.

Comment: I just rereproduced the error. Unfortunately, this is not productive enough to continue during work hours. More on it when I have spare time.

Comment: `char_length` and `length`: You're right. I missed this.

Comment: Note that a Stored Routine takes on the `CHARACTER SET` _at the time of creation_.  This could explain why recreating it fixed it.